# Qt Color Conditions

Tags: python, pyqt5, abstracttablemodel

I am using PyQt5 to create an abstract table model. I'm wondering if there is a way to essentially say "return this color if the cell above is also that color". For instance, a certain cell is colored green based on a series of conditions. I also need certain cells to be colored green that are below the first green cell based on slightly different criteria, one of which being that the cell above it is also green. Is there a way in Qt to pull the information or metadata about a cell in order to use it in my algorithm?

Comment: Please publish your example.

Comment: I can't. It is for a project where some of the required criteria are indicators of proprietary information.

Comment: @Ejtunison Of course you can - just write a simplified example based on your real code that demonstrates your requirements. As it is, your question is far too vague to answer in a constructive way.